# FFT subtraction - OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, fft, dft

I am working on an image and I want to delete the background from it. To do that I am going to use the DFT and then subtract the differences between my Image and the background(+noisy stuff).

What I need is to understand why I am getting the same result if I do the following stuff:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal


#### FFT SUBSTRACT
#Extract image
CellImg = cv2.imread(r'cell.jpg',0)
BackImg = cv2.imread(r'back.jpg',0)

#Covnert to 32 float
CellImg_float32 = np.float32(CellImg)
BackImg_float32 = np.float32(BackImg)

print("Size Cell: "+str(np.shape(CellImg_float32)))
print("Size Back: "+str(np.shape(BackImg_float32)))

# DFT
dft_CellImg_float32 = cv2.dft(CellImg_float32, flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
dft_shift_CellImg_float32 = np.fft.fftshift(dft_CellImg_float32)

dft_BackImg_float32 = cv2.dft(BackImg_float32, flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
dft_shift_BackImg_float32 = np.fft.fftshift(dft_BackImg_float32)

# Subtract and inverse: CELL - BACKGROUND
dft_diff_cmb = dft_shift_CellImg_float32 - dft_shift_BackImg_float32
SubFFTImg_inverse_cmb = cv2.idft(np.fft.ifftshift(dft_diff_cmb))
SubFFTImg_cmb = cv2.magnitude(SubFFTImg_inverse_cmb[:,:,0],SubFFTImg_inverse_cmb[:,:,1])

# Subtract and inverse: BACKGROUND - CELL
dft_diff_bmc = dft_shift_BackImg_float32 - dft_shift_CellImg_float32
SubFFTImg_inverse_bmc = cv2.idft(np.fft.ifftshift(dft_diff_bmc))
SubFFTImg_bmc = cv2.magnitude(SubFFTImg_inverse_bmc[:,:,0],SubFFTImg_inverse_bmc[:,:,1])

# Plot Init image -> (Image - Background) & (Background - Image)
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(231),plt.imshow(CellImg, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(232),plt.imshow(BackImg, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Background'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(233),plt.imshow(SubFFTImg_cmb, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Image - Background'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(234),plt.imshow(CellImg, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(235),plt.imshow(BackImg, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Background'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(236),plt.imshow(SubFFTImg_bmc, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Background - Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

The results are the following:

- Test n°1:
  [image: Test n°1: Cell - Background]
- Test n°2:
  [image: Test n°2: FullAcq. - whitebox]

What I am asking here is: why am i getting the same result if I subtract in one time (image - back) and in the second (back - image) ? Shouldn't I get the exact opposite results? If not, what am I missing?

Thanks you all!

p.s.: yep firsts images are low Q, I just need to understand why I'm getting this result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the same result with `image-background` and `background-image` because you are taking the absolute value of the result: you are actually comparing `abs(image-background)` and `abs(background-image)`, which are identical by definition (you are using `cv2.magnitude`, which computes the absolute value).

---

Do note that computing `abs(ifft(fft(image)-fft(background)))` is the same as simply computing `abs(image-background)`. There is no need to go to the Fourier domain for addition and subtraction. This is because the Fourier transform is a linear function. A linear function `T` is characterized by `T(ax+by) == a*T(x) + b*T(y)`, with `a` and `b` constants. Therefore, the addition or subtraction can be performed before or after the Fourier transform to yield the same result

The Fourier domain is useful for computing the convolution: `conv(x,y) == ifft(fft(x)*fft(y))`.

Comment: Yep right I didnt thought about magnitude...
Thanks :)